# Python target file base on date in filename

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a weird request.

I have this folder structure

```
.
├── file-2021.08.01.json
├── file-2021.08.02.json
└── file-2021.08.03.json
```

and a script that needs to open one of those files to send some azure service bus messages. The script looks like this:

```
with open('file-2021.08.02.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for key in data:
        for value in key.values():
            print(key)
            to_queue.append(key)
```

this I, unfortunately, a hard coded path to the file. but as I wanted that `open('file-2021.08.02.json')` to be dynamically allocated based on the date in the filename. this is what I mean

those files in the folder, are some json files coming from a logstash, which they get generated on a daily basis. What I would like to achieve with this, is to run my script to know what is the previous date (the yesterday date) and match it with the file name, and pass that output to the `with open`.

can anyone please help to solve this issue and how can I achieve this?

Comment: have a look at the ```datetime``` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Yes thank you. It's works z